# A question on connected components of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

It must be a simple question but I cannot see clearly. Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $C$ is a connected component of $X$. We can write $X=C\cup (X\setminus C)$. My question is: why we have
$\overline C\cap(X\setminus C)=C\cap\overline{(X\setminus C)}=\emptyset? $ For the first intersection we can argue that since connected components are closed, this is the same as $C\cap(X\setminus C)=\emptyset$. But how about the second intersection? Why it is empty? Thanks for any reply.

Comment: This is not true in general.  Are there some additional hypotheses you have omitted?

Comment: Suppose $X=\mathbb{R}^n$. Does it help, or additional hypotheses on $C$ are needed?

Comment: @M.Rahmat: $\Bbb R^n$ is connected, so its only component is itself.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: yes, but still $\mathbb{R}^n\cap \overline{\emptyset}=\emptyset$ holds. The sets $X\setminus C$ may be empty.

Comment: Suppose $X = \mathbb{Q}$. Then $\overline{X\setminus C} = X$. Generally, $C \cap \overline{X\setminus C} = \varnothing$ means $C$ is open. If $X$ is locally connected, then components are closed and open.

Comment: @M.Rahmat: My point was that in that case it’s completely trivial and uninteresting.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer. Your comment answered all my questions. Thanks